# Как найти указываемое подмножество в рамках указываемого множества с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения, sublime-text-3

- https://regex101.com/r/FxYgQ7/2

  1. Регулярка: `(<p\s.*?>)(.*?\.)(<\/p>)`
  2. Вход: `<p class="c01">String1.String2.String3.</p>`
  3. Выход: `<p class="c01">String1. <span>...</span> String2. <span>...</span> String3. <span>...</span> </p>`

Во 2-й группе регулярки `(.*?\.)` должно на мой взгляд находится собственно "волшебство". Чтобы ST3 не находил как сейчас полностью `String1.String2.String3.`, а выходил с каждым нажатием F3 поочередно на `String1.` –> `String2.` –> `String3.`

**Попробую еще сократить**

- Входные данные: `<p>lorem ipsum. dolor sit. amet sed.</p>`
- Регэксп: `\.\s`
- Выходные данные будут добавляться между предложениями: `<p>lorem ipsum. # dolor sit. # amet sed. #</p>`.
- **ВОПРОС:** Как сделать, чтобы поиск не покидал содержимого тегов `<p>`,`</p>` (или других заданных) **?**

  - **ИЛИ**, переиначиваю: **КАК** добавить символ (#, например) после каждой точки в предложении. **НО** только в пределах тегов `<p>`,`</p>` **?**

Comment: не особо-то вы подходящий инструмент взяли для модификации html

Comment: Надо после `StringN` вставить ` <span>...</span> ` независимо, где этот `StringN` находится? Приведите однозначные примеры текстов в соответствии с описанием метки [tag:регулярные-выражения]

Comment: Если бы независимо, то вопросов нет. Мы должны найти множество, т.е, всё, что внутри <p class="c01">...</p>. А там предложения. Их нам надо видоизменить добавив <span>...</span>. В остальные <p>, <pre> и прочие теги не соваться.

Comment: Ещё раз -- приведите однозначные примеры "вход-выход", а не объясняйте словами

Comment: То есть как это должно, на мой взгляд работать. Поставил я в поле поиска в ST3 регулярку. В поле замены поставил $1 <span class="my_class">...</span> $4. Как еще уточнить? Рекурсия, итерация, цикл... в рамках regex такое возможно? Если бы это был какой-то ЯП, это было бы наверно "пройтись по массиву".

Comment: @dIm0n Вход--выход: https://regex101.com/r/FxYgQ7/2

Comment: Добавьте это в вопрос с помощью кнопки править (содержимое ссылки тоже, а не чисто ссылку)

Comment: @dIm0n, да пожалуйста.

Comment: Чувствую, задача оказалась "со звездочкой". Вроде бы проще некуда. Ответ нужен можно/нельзя. Не одного коммента по сути стоящего, кроме, наверно, самого первого. Но что инструментов для этой задачи несчетное количество, и так понятно. Вопрос же можно ли это проделать средствами редактора кода.

Comment: Желание помогать после таких комментариев пропадает

Comment: @dIm0n, да ладно тебе. Помощь при оформлении тоже нужна. А ответ все равно нужен и мы/вы его найдем. Даже если эту тему удалят, пересоздам и сам отвечу. Я считаю вопрос важным для начинающего пользователя регулярок.

Comment: Помочь с решением можно только при понимании условия. Если вам до сих пор не помогли ни Wiktor Stribiżew, ни PotroNik, ни Qwertiy, ни я (извиняюсь, кого забыл из активных отвечающих по метке), то это о чём-то говорит

Comment: А еще кто нибудь выскажется, кроме Вас, @dIm0n? По теме собственно вопроса. Ни Wiktor Stribiżew, ни PotroNik, ни Qwertiy ?

Comment: @hamonEveryBody Ваша проблема решается просто, нужно найти один шаблон между двумя *разными* другими шаблонами. В SublimeText используется библиотека PCRE, она поддерживает всё необходимое.

Comment: Спасибо преогромное, уже проверяю. Сорян, что раньше не смог.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать

```js
(?s)(?:\G(?!\A)|<p>)(?:(?!<p>).)*?\K\.(?=.*?</p>)
```

См. [пример использования регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/5I7SP0/1/).

До:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
После:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Подробности**

- `(?s)` - симол точки теперь также находит переносы строки
- `(?:\G(?!\A)|<p>)` - `<p>` или конец предыдущего удачного совпадения
- `(?:(?!<p>).)*?` - любой символ, 0 и более повторов, но как можно меньше, который не является первым символом последовательности символов `<p>`
- `\K` - оператор, удаляющий весь текст из буфера текущего совпадения
- `\.` - символ `.`
- `(?=.*?</p>)` - блок просмотра вперёд, который требует наличия подстроки `</p>` после 0 и более любых символов (как можно меньше).

Comment: Это просто бомба!!! А как добавить к <p> класс? Конечно разбираться и разбираться ещё...

Comment: timeout ещё какой-то на regex101, не пойму как усмирить.... Залогинился — помогло!

Comment: Что значит "добавить к `<p>` класс"? Какая у вас строка на входе? Какой там таймаут? Поделитесь ссылкой на тест на regex101.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/5I7SP0/3

Comment: @hamonEveryBody https://regex101.com/r/5I7SP0/5

Comment: Как выцепить из тегов только <p> c классом c01, при наличии такого кода <p class="c01 c02 c03 nnn> Заранее извиняюсь за тупняк, забыл уже всё)

Comment: @hamonEveryBody `(?s)(?:\G(?!\A)|<p(?:\s[^>]*)?\sclass="(?:[^"]*\s)?c01[\s"])(?:(?!<p[\s>]).)*?\K\.(?=.*?</p>)` - [пример](https://regex101.com/r/5I7SP0/7).

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116248/discussion-between-hamoneverybody-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: Это просто невероятно))) Работает именно так, как надо. Где бы вы не находились, Виктор, в Варшаве, Москве, Лондоне... Большое Человеческое Вам СПАСИБО!

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать такой вариант, здесь мы допускаем всевозможные символы, кроме открывающегося тега:

```
(<p\s.*?>)([^<]*?\.)(<\/p>)
```

А если нужно, чтобы регулярное выражение выделяло все символы, включая и другие теги внутри `p`, то на вашем примере работает такое вырежение:

```
(<p\s.*?>)(.*?)(<\/p>)
```

По идее, основное ограничение на `p`-теги у вас уже есть. А вам нужно было убрать точку с конца во второй группе.

https://regex101.com/r/FxYgQ7/9

Comment: Вы сами хоть проверили это выражение? Оно никак не может помочь в данном случае. Оно найдёт [ровно то же](https://regex101.com/r/FxYgQ7/8), что и [выражение в вопросе](https://regex101.com/r/FxYgQ7/2).

Comment: Так а вам какое регулярное выражение нужно? Вам нужно, чтобы оно ещё обрабатывало и `span`-теги?